# Book on history of international trade

Tags: trade

I have just finished reading the book Taipan by James Clavell and I am fascinated by the history of International Trade and merchants and how they have affected the course of history.  Can I get a recommendation of a good book about the history of International Trade and also a book with more of a focus on Asia/China?

A quick search on Amazon has turned up "A Splendid Exchange: How Trade Shaped the World".  Any other books out there that you would recommend?

Comment: Welcome to History SE! Any question that solicits sources, lists, discussion, or opinions is not appropriate for this site. Please ask if you have any specific questions!

Comment: I am going to convert this to a community wiki. I can see some relevance in the request, but it doesn't truly fit our question/answer model. As Luke stated, asking for recommendations that result in a list or ongoing discussions doesn't really fit within our guidelines.

Comment: Assent Of Money?

Answer (score 1):

You can learn surprisingly much about the history of international trade from "Kicking Away the Ladder: Development Strategy in Historical Perspective: Policies and Institutions for Economic Development in Historical Perspective", by Ha-Joon Chang.